# Simple Multivariate Bayesian Method in Python

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, python, pymc

I am trying to follow the Bayesian method described in [this text](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter2_MorePyMC/Chapter2.ipynb). The python notebook goes through the example of creating two Poisson functions describing a change in SMS frequency at some point tau.

But I want to explore multivariate methods, so instead will start  with simply two time changes (tau1 and tau2) with three exponentials (lambda1, lambda2, lambda3). As described in the text, I can create the exponential multivariate lambdas_ as follows:

```
import pymc as pm
alpha = 1.0/count_data.mean()

lambdas_ = pm.Exponential("lambda_1", alpha, size=3)
tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data, size=2)
```

My simple and obvious (not to me!) mistake occurs in defining the deterministic lambda_ function

```
@pm.deterministic
def lambda_(tau=tau, lambdas_=lambdas_):
    out = np.zeros(n_count_data)
    out[:tau[0]] = lambda_[0]  # lambda before tau is lambda1
    out[tau[0]:tau[1]] = lambda_[1]  # lambda between tau1 and tau2 is lambda2
    out[tau[1]:] = lambda_1[2] # lambda after tau2 is lambda3
    return out
```

I am wondering if this is the proper method for determining the expectations based on the posteriors, as in determining when are we in the regime of which lambda and particularly for determining idx2 which seems odd to use a product (otherwise i get the numpy complaint of using a.any() or a.all() if i just do `tau_samples[:,0] <= day < tau_samples[:,1]`):

```
# tau_samples, lambdas_samples contain
# N samples from the corresponding posterior distribution
N = tau_samples.shape[0]
expected_texts_per_day = np.zeros(n_count_data)
for day in range(0, n_count_data):
    # ix is a bool index of all tau samples corresponding to
    # the switchpoint occurring prior to value of 'day'
    ix1 = day < tau_samples[:,0]
    ix2 = np.prod([tau_samples[:,0] <= day, day < tau_samples[:,1]],axis=0)
    ix3 = tau_samples[:,1] <= day
    # Each posterior sample corresponds to a value for tau.
    # for each day, that value of tau indicates whether we're "before"
    # (in the lambdas_[0] "regime"), "between" (in the lambdas_[1] "regime") or
    #  "after" (in the lambdas_[2] "regime") the switchpoint.
    # by taking the posterior sample of lambda1/2/3 accordingly, we can average
    # over all samples to get an expected value for lambda on that day.
    # As explained, the "message count" random variable is Poisson distributed,
    # and therefore lambda (the poisson parameter) is the expected value of
    # "message count".
    expected_texts_per_day[day] = (lambdas_samples[ix1,0].sum()
                                   + lambdas_samples[ix2,1].sum()
                                   + lambdas_samples[ix3,2].sum()) / N
```

I would appreciate any feedback, thank you for your time and guidance. I have pasted the full code below

```
import json, matplotlib
s = json.load( open("bmh_matplotlibrc.json") )
matplotlib.rcParams.update(s)

%matplotlib osx
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figsize(11, 9)

import scipy.stats as stats

figsize(12.5, 3.5)
count_data = np.loadtxt("txtdata.csv")
n_count_data = len(count_data)
plt.bar(np.arange(n_count_data), count_data, color="#348ABD")
plt.xlabel("Time (days)")
plt.ylabel("count of text-msgs received")
plt.title("Did the user's texting habits change over time?")
plt.xlim(0, n_count_data);

import pymc as pm

alpha = 1.0 / count_data.mean()  # Recall count_data is the
                               # variable that holds our txt counts

lambdas_ = pm.Exponential("lambda_", alpha, size=3)
tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=n_count_data, size=2)

@pm.deterministic
def lambda_(tau=tau, lambdas_=lambdas_):
    out = np.zeros(n_count_data)
    out[:tau[0]] = lambdas_[0]  # lambda before tau is lambda1
    out[tau[0]:tau[1]] = lambdas_[1]  # lambda between tau1 and tau2 is lambda2
    out[tau[1]:] = lambdas_[2] # lambda after tau2 is lambda3
    return out

observation = pm.Uniform("obs", lambda_, value=count_data, observed=True)
model = pm.Model([observation, lambdas_, taus])

mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(40000, 10000, 1)

lambdas_samples = mcmc.trace('lambdas_')[:]
tau_samples = mcmc.trace('tau')[:]

import random
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
cols=[]
[cols.append('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())) for i in range(5)]

figsize(8.5, 14)
# histogram of the samples:

ax = plt.subplot(511)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)

plt.hist(lambdas_samples[:,0], histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_1$", color=cols[0], normed=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title(r"""Posterior distributions of the variables
    $\lambda_1,\;\lambda_2,\;\lambda_3,\;\tau_1,\;\tau_2$""")
plt.xlim([0, 30])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_1$ value")

ax = plt.subplot(512)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)
plt.hist(lambdas_samples[:,1], histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_2$", color=cols[1], normed=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlim([0, 30])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_2$ value")

ax = plt.subplot(513)
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)
plt.hist(lambdas_samples[:,2], histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.85,
         label="posterior of $\lambda_3$", color=cols[2], normed=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.xlim([0, 30])
plt.xlabel("$\lambda_3$ value")

plt.subplot(514)
w = 1.0 / tau_samples[:,0].shape[0] * np.ones_like(tau_samples[:,0])
plt.hist(tau_samples[:,0], bins=n_count_data, alpha=1,
         label=r"posterior of $\tau_1$",
         color=cols[3], weights=w, rwidth=2.)
plt.xticks(np.arange(n_count_data))

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim([0, .75])
plt.xlim([20, len(count_data) - 20])
plt.xlabel(r"$\tau_1$ (in days)")
plt.ylabel("probability");

plt.subplot(515)
w = 1.0 / tau_samples[:,1].shape[0] * np.ones_like(tau_samples[:,1])
plt.hist(tau_samples[:,1], bins=n_count_data, alpha=1,
         label=r"posterior of $\tau_2$",
         color=cols[4], weights=w, rwidth=2.)
plt.xticks(np.arange(n_count_data))

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim([0, .75])
plt.xlim([20, len(count_data) - 20])
plt.xlabel(r"$\tau_2$ (in days)")
plt.ylabel("probability");

figsize(12.5, 5)
# tau_samples, lambdas_samples contain
# N samples from the corresponding posterior distribution
N = tau_samples.shape[0]
expected_texts_per_day = np.zeros(n_count_data)
for day in range(0, n_count_data):
    # ix is a bool index of all tau samples corresponding to
    # the switchpoint occurring prior to value of 'day'
    ix1 = day < tau_samples[:,0]
    ix2 = np.prod([tau_samples[:,0] <= day, day < tau_samples[:,1]],axis=0)
    ix3 = tau_samples[:,1] <= day
    # Each posterior sample corresponds to a value for tau.
    # for each day, that value of tau indicates whether we're "before"
    # (in the lambdas_[0] "regime"), "between" (in the lambdas_[1] "regime") or
    #  "after" (in the lambdas_[2] "regime") the switchpoint.
    # by taking the posterior sample of lambda1/2/3 accordingly, we can average
    # over all samples to get an expected value for lambda on that day.
    # As explained, the "message count" random variable is Poisson distributed,
    # and therefore lambda (the poisson parameter) is the expected value of
    # "message count".
    expected_texts_per_day[day] = (lambdas_samples[ix1,0].sum()
                                   + lambdas_samples[ix2,1].sum()
                                   + lambdas_samples[ix3,2].sum()) / N


plt.plot(range(n_count_data), expected_texts_per_day, lw=4, color="#E24A33",
         label="expected number of text-messages received")
plt.xlim(0, n_count_data)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("Expected # text-messages")
plt.title("Expected number of text-messages received")
plt.ylim(0, 60)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(count_data)), count_data, color="#348ABD", alpha=0.65,
        label="observed texts per day")

plt.legend(loc="upper left");
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is here? Also, please paste in whatever information is necessary to understand your question. People aren't going to want to go & read something else to be able to answer your question.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, i've added the full code and explained my issue of determining the expectation based on posterior samples.

Answer (score 3):

Your PyMC code looks correct - can you confirm that the model converges well too? There's no point in computing statistics on top of your posteriors if your model hasn't converged yet.

Assuming it has converged, your calculation of the expected value looks good, and your use of `prod` look fine. Alternatively, you could do

`(tau_samples[:,0] <= day) * (day < tau_samples[:,1])`

Does that help?